# Unique combination of two columns in mysql or postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have to get unique combinations of two columns.

Eg if the values are :

```
sender_id   recipient_id   created_at

    1            2         10/11/2014
    2            1         10/12/2014 
    1            2         10/13/2014
    1            3         10/14/2014
```

I want the output to be :

```
sender_id   recipient_id   created_at

    1            3         10/14/2014
    1            2         10/13/2014
```

I wrote this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (sender_id, recipient_id) *
FROM "messages"
WHERE ((recipient_id = 1 and recipient_delete = false) 
    or (sender_id = 1 and sender_delete = false))
ORDER BY sender_id, recipient_id, created_at DESC
```

But it outputs this:

```
sender_id   recipient_id   created_at

    1            3         10/14/2014
    2            1         10/12/2014 
    1            2         10/13/2014
```

Comment: I'm confused, (1, 2) is not unique. Are you sure those are your expected results?

Comment: @McAdam331 Sorry I didn't get you ...

Comment: You said you want unique combinations of two columns, but (1, 2) isn't unique, it appears twice? Or do you mean a unique combination of (1, 2) OR (2, 1)?

Comment: The query will definitely not output that since in none of those is `sender_id` or `recipient_id` 4.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yeah .. please check now I have updated the ID

Comment: @McAdam331 I mean if two rows are  (1, 2) and  (2, 1), it should only return one row order by created_at i.e (1, 2)

Comment: @SachinPrasad, you're getting the sender_id of 2 because of this line in your where clause: (recipient_id = 1 and recipient_delete = false)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option to get all pairs, regardless of whether they are forward or backward (for example (1, 2) == (2, 1)) is to select the `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` from each row, and then select distinct values. Using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id), GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id)
FROM myTable;
```

You will get the following output:

```
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
```

Once you have that, you can GROUP by these to get the maximum date for each pair:

```
SELECT LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id), GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id), MAX(created_at)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id), GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id);
```

This query will give you the data you need for each pair, but it won't return the actual row from your original table. If there is a row of format `| 2 | 1 | 2014-10-15 |` this query will return `| 1 | 2 | 2014-10-15`.

To get the original row from your table, you need to `JOIN` on the condition that all of the necessary columns match:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id) AS least, 
    GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id) AS greatest,
    MAX(created_at) AS maxDate
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id), GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id)) tmp
ON tmp.least = LEAST(m.sender_id, m.recipient_id) AND tmp.greatest = GREATEST(m.sender_id, m.recipient_id) AND tmp.maxDate = m.created_at;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cc9e/4) example that matches your expected results.

Comment: Thanks its working, I hope I don't have to optimize this query in the future as most of our work is dependent on this.

Comment: @SachinPrasad if you have any trouble just come back and ask, I'll try to help.

Answer (score 4):

The initial idea with `DISTINCT ON` is good, but:

- it works with postgres but not with mysql, `DISTINCT ON()` being a PostgreSQL non-standard extension.
- the ON() has to be applied to an expression where (1,2) and (2,1) are equivalent.

So a close query that should work and be efficient for postgres is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pair) *,
    CASE WHEN sender_id<recipient_id
      THEN (sender_id,recipient_id)
      ELSE (recipient_id,sender_id)
    END AS pair
FROM messages
ORDER BY pair, created_at DESC ;
```

Comment: wow that's a great ... couldn't be more simpler and shorter than this !

Comment: I also need unread messages count with the same query. Can you please help me on this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381765/rows-count-without-distinct