# Rows count without distinct

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pair) *,
    CASE WHEN sender_id<recipient_id
      THEN (sender_id,recipient_id)
      ELSE (recipient_id,sender_id)
    END AS pair FROM "messages" WHERE 
    ((recipient_id = 6 and recipient_delete = false) or 
    (sender_id = 6 and sender_delete = false))  
    GROUP BY messages.id
    ORDER BY  pair, created_at, unread_count DESC
```

Which brings latest message of a conversation of a user(User Inbox).

Now I need to show total unread messages counts for each conversation, there is a flag in the table 'opened', which states whether a message is unread or not.

This is the query I wrote for it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pair) *,
    CASE WHEN sender_id<recipient_id
      THEN (sender_id,recipient_id)
      ELSE (recipient_id,sender_id)
    END AS pair, COUNT(messages.opened= false) AS unread_count FROM "messages" WHERE 
    ((recipient_id = 6 and recipient_delete = false) or 
    (sender_id = 6 and sender_delete = false))  
    GROUP BY messages.id
    ORDER BY  pair, created_at, unread_count DESC
```

But it shows count a 1 even when there are more than 2 or 3 messages(I guess this is because of Distinct).

Any idea?

If you need to know why we have user `CASE WHEN` function please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621582/unique-combination-of-two-columns-in-mysql-or-postgres) :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused, because your logic would appear to bring the *earliest* message not the latest one.

Although `distinct on` is quite powerful, I'm not sure if you can readily get what you want.  My inclination is to switch to using window functions:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (SELECT m.*,
             (CASE WHEN sender_id < recipient_id
                   THEN (sender_id, recipient_id)
                   ELSE (recipient_id, sender_id)
              END) AS pair,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN sender_id < recipient_id
                                                   THEN (sender_id, recipient_id)
                                                   ELSE (recipient_id, sender_id)
                                              END)
                                ORDER BY created_at, unread_count DESC
                               ) as seqnum,
             SUM(CASE WHEN m.opened = false THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER
                 (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN sender_id < recipient_id
                                     THEN (sender_id, recipient_id)
                                     ELSE (recipient_id, sender_id)
                                END)
                 ) as NumUnopened
      FROM "messages" m
      WHERE ((recipient_id = 6 and recipient_delete = false) or 
             (sender_id = 6 and sender_delete = false))  
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: What is the difference between  earliest message not the latest one. Also please note that I need  unread message count for each conversation, instead of a total count.

Comment: I'm getting this error:  ERROR:  column "m.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

Select the field "messages.opened" (Alias messages_opened) in your Query and then surround them like this:

select count(messages_opened)
FROM (... [your query] ) as A
where A.messages_opened = false

Query for Example:

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE 
  ( 
     messageid   INT, 
     senderid    INT, 
     recipientid INT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @table 
            (messageid, 
             senderid, 
             recipientid) 
VALUES      (1, 
             10, 
             20), 
            (2, 
             10, 
             20), 
            (3, 
             11, 
             20), 
            (4, 
             11, 
             20), 
            (5, 
             10, 
             20) 

SELECT Count(messageid) AS countOfMessages, 
       senderid, 
       recipientid 
FROM   @table 
GROUP  BY senderid, 
          recipientid
```

Comment: I want unread message count for each conversation, instead of a total count. Sorry for confusion ..

Comment: then add a "group by" and count each conversation.

like this:select COUNT(messageId) as countOfMessages, senderID, recipientId from @table
group by senderID,recipientId